# Elixir Dynamo : Keep Data after redirect

Tags: routes, elixir, cowboy

Is there a way to handle data transfert from a router request to another route ?

Lets say, I'm handling a request, like a create, or a delete, or something alike, by themselves, theses actions don't have any views, and will redirect the request to another route.
But, I'd like to also send a "success" message, stating that well it ended well, or not.

If I remember well my Rails days, there was something like *flash* that did that kind of stuff. Is there already something similar in Dynamo ? Or do I need to brew something myself ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support for flash messages in Dynamo. You will have to brew your own. :)